# Append autocomplete selection to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulty appending selected autocomplete values to a textarea for building a sentence. In other words, as users choose values from autocomplete, they will get inserted between `default_text_1` and `default_text_2`.

The end goal here is to attach the original selected value and be able to remove selections inline from the textarea.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="pieces" />

<br />

<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

JS

```
var default_text_1 = "Colors to enjoy are: ";
var default_text_2 = ". There may be others.";

$("#textarea").val(default_text_1 + default_text_2);

var availableColors = [ { label: "Blue", value: "1" }, { label: "Yellow", value: "2" }, { label: "Green", value: "3" } ];

$( "#pieces" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    source: availableColors;
    $("#textarea").val(default_text_1 + availableColors.val + default_text_2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are small issues with your options object:

```
{
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    source: availableColors;
    $("#textarea").val(default_text_1 + availableColors.val + default_text_2);
  }
}
```

- `source` should not be in `select`'s function
- `availableColors.val` doesn't exist (I assumed you wanted to concat the selected `label`

I believe this will help get you going:

```js
var default_text_1 = "Colors to enjoy are: ";
var default_text_2 = ". There may be others.";

$("#textarea").val(default_text_1 + default_text_2);

var availableColors = [ { label: "Blue", value: "1" }, { label: "Yellow", value: "2" }, { label: "Green", value: "3" } ];

$("#pieces").autocomplete({
  source: availableColors,
  select: function ( event, ui ) {
    let val = $("#textarea").val();
    $("#textarea").val(
      val.split(default_text_2)
         .concat([ui.item.label, default_text_2])
         .join(' ')
    );
    //Remove next two statements if you don't want #pieces cleared
    $('#pieces').val('');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pieces" />

<br />

<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

You'll likely want to clear `#pieces` on selection so that the selection value isn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this working code

```js
var default_text_1 = "Colors to enjoy are: ";
var default_text_2 = ". There may be others.";

$("#textarea").val(default_text_1 + default_text_2);

var availableColors = [{
  label: "Blue",
  value: "1"
 },
 {
  label: "Yellow",
  value: "2"
 },
 {
  label: "Green",
  value: "3"
 }
];

$("#pieces").autocomplete({

 source: availableColors,
 select: function (event, ui) {
  $("#textarea").val(default_text_1 + ui.item.label + default_text_2);


 }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<input type="text" id="pieces" />

<br />

<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```